# Remove c#-4.5 tag

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The [c#-4.5](/questions/tagged/c%23-4.5) tag should be removed and possibly added as a synonym for the [c#-5.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-5.0) tag. People get confused a lot, but .NET 4.5 ships with C# 5.0.

Comment: Bah!  I never thought to search for it, so I never saw it.  We should flog those who used that tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just retag all 10 (as of this writing) questions and after 24 hours the tag will disappear.

Comment: Didn't know tags can be removed this way - thanks.

Comment: All occurrences of the tag have been removed.

Comment: It might be worth adding to the blacklist though, once the existing posts are fixed.  It's the type of thing that's likely to continue to pop up again and again.

Comment: @Servy - if it comes back, yes. The fact that it takes a fair amount of rep to create a tag on SO will help reduce the chances of it reappearing.

Comment: @Servy Also, it would have to come back like gangbusters in order to  be blacklisted.  10 questions doesn't really warrant a blacklist.

Comment: @casperOne Well, since it just came out recently, not many people are using it.  I'm assuming that once it starts being used by a more significant percentage of the users in the C# tag we'll start seeing more people trying to tag questions with C# 5/.NET 4.5 content, and thus more people *incorrectly* tagging such content.  As of now, there just aren't many people trying to use it.

Comment: @Servy Take a look at my profile on SO, I think you'll realize that I know that .NET 4.5/c# 5.0 came out recently =)  Point is, for better or worse, blacklists come about *after* it's been shown it's needed, not before.